# GTM Regex for URL onl 3 layers down

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

I have no clue why this isn't working for. I keep looking at it but it's killing me.

I want my GTM trigger to fire on pages three layers down but not any furster (or before). This is the script I have

```
www.example.com/cat|dog/.*/^[a-z0-9-]+$
```

I tried ending it with [^/] but it wouldn't work. I am seriously stumped here.

For example I want it to match:

- www.example.com/cat/nsw/one
- www.example.com/dog/qld/three

But I don't want it to match

- www.example.com/cat/nsw/one/house
- www.example.com/dog/qld/three/home/tags
- www.example.com/dog
- www.example.com

Any help would be great!

Comment: If cheating is allowed you could use a custom js variable instead of regex - split the path by "/" and look at the length of the resulting array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^www\.example\.com/(cat|dog)/[^/]+/[a-z0-9-]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7S1Xwi/1)

Note:

- Escape the `.` that is a literal dot
- Use `^` at the start to make sure you start matching at the start of the string
- Group alternatives if they occur in  the middle of the pattern or you will break the pattern (`(dog|cat)`)
- Instead of a greedy dot pattern, use a negated character class to restrict `.`, and only match any chars but the selected one(s).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `www\.example\.com/` - a literal `www.example.com/` substring
- `(cat|dog)` - either `cat` or `dog`
- `/` - a slash
- `[^/]+` - 1+ chars other than `/`
- `/` - a `/`
- `[a-z0-9-]+` - 1+ lowercase ASCII lettes or digits or `-` (add `A-Z` after `[` to also match uppercase)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks so much I can see where I went wrong now. *duh*